# New learner Golang. Why does my local variable saved between call?

Tags: algorithm, go, debugging

I have a problem with local variable "i". The second time i call nextEven, i think "i" should be intitialized back to 0. But the value "i" is saved in "makeEvengenerator()".

```
package main

import "fmt"

func makeEvengenerator() func() int {
    i:=0
    return func() (ret int) {
        ret = i
        i += 2
        return ret
    }

}
func main() {
    nextEven := makeEvengenerator()
    fmt.Println(nextEven())
    fmt.Println(nextEven())
    fmt.Println(nextEven())
}
```

I expected in to print out 0 0 0
Also I dont understand why everytime I call nextEven(), the code "i:=0" dont run again everytime i call the nextEven()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The second time i call nextEven, i think "i" should be intitialized back to 0

Why would it ? If you **really want** to reinitialize 0, then you can do:

```
func makeEvengenerator() func() int {
    return func() (ret int) {
        i := 0
        ret = i
        i += 2
        return ret
    }

}
```

But it would not make much sense as you usually want a closure to encapsulate a state or dependencies.

You can get some documentation and alternate examples [here](https://www.golangprograms.com/higher-order-functions-in-golang.html).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But i still don't understand why when i call my var nextEven(which I intialized with makeEvengenerator ), the code "i := 0" don't run again everytime i call it.

Comment: Because nextEven is not your `makeEvengenerator`. It is the function returned by it, which does not run `i := 0`